# How to get the fillColor of overlay shapes in Google maps?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, properties, overlay

Look at this code: a is an object we save a circle overlay inside. In Google maps we can get type{polygon, circle, rectangle, marker, polyline} or center{circle}, etc. Imagine you create a circle on the map. How can you get something like this: 
    **a.fillColor = circle.fillColor;**

```
<script>
function getProprties()
{
    var a = {};

    a.type = circle.type;
    a.center = circle.center;
    a.redius = circle.radius;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean `a = circle` ?

Comment: No. I want to get the color of circle. Something like a = circle.fillColor;

Comment: could you use `circle.get('fillColor')` ?

Comment: Yes It works for me. Thank you very much. I used it before but it shown me error something like: "there is no fillColor method" but now it words for me.

Comment: @Duncan, you should post it as an Answer, so that Sponge Bob can mark your answer as Accepted. (to so the question gets marked as Answered)

Comment: @barryhunter thanks for the prompt, I wasn't sure if my suggestion would work, so I didn't want to post it as an answer initially

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use this, using the `get` function available on all [MVCObjects](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MVCObject)

```
a.fillColor = circle.get('fillColor');
```